# inplview.debug.js object required error with custom field ascx and jquery

Tags: custom-field-types

I am creating a new custom field.  Within the user control (ascx) I am using a watermark pluggin.

I have added the custom field to a list.  After an iisreset, the first time IN Internet Explorer 8 when I try to add a new list item I get the following error

With testing I have even removed all the functionality in the pluggin and this still occurs.  If i just close the add new item window and try it again i do not get this error message.  I only occurs once and inside of IE

Ideas?

```
    Webpage error details
```

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC EA 2; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Wed, 18 May 2011 21:41:50 UTC

Message: Object required
Line: 1732
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://{server}/_layouts/inplview.debug.js?rev=Pea6rD0hm%2B3qGltzhljeGQ%3D%3D

Comment: I found that, on the first page hit (subsequent pages do not load them) the following JavaScript references were being downloaded (size in Bytes shown in brackets):
core.js (237,096)
sp.core.js (12,349)
cui.js (351,361)
sp.ui.dialog.js (34,243)
sp.runtime.js (68,784)
sp.js (389,372)
inplview.js (38,836)

Comment: David, is this a multiple server farm? If so make sure the js files are of the deployed on all servers. We had some trouble with core.js in a farm scenario because of mismatched js files.

Answer (score 2):

Having an "Object required" related to JS means that the script has an instruction at line such-and-such that tries to access a property or method on a variable that has not been assigned a value of type [object] before accessing. It's much like the NullReferenceException in .NET if that gives you a clue.

Try using the Internet Explorer developer tools (F12) where you can enable JS debugging and in most cases see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Apparently, one of the scripts that defines the object is loaded later than inplview.debug.js and cached. That makes the script work on subsequent page loads.